# Forward 443 request to private server from public server

Tags: nginx, https

I have two servers. The first is public and the second is private. So, public server has nginx with virtual site config which handle https requests (port 443). I need to forward that requests to private server which has https certificate config.

How to config nginx to redirect https requests from first server to private server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use one of following aproch to redirect your request,

1) Redirect 301:

```
server {
listen       80;
listen       [::]:80;
return 301 https://your2ndHost$request_uri;
}
```

2) Using rewrite:

```
 location / {
       rewrite ^ https://your2ndHost?url=$1? last;
}
```

3) Using proxy

```
 location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://your2ndHost;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's right but I have to config ssl certificate on public server otherwise the browser reports an error (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). My idea is to config the certificate on private server. Cloud I perform implementation like this?

Comment: @EugeneKirin You need to add SSL on public and it's mandatory, adding SSL to private network it's your choice, but if you are not adding SSL to your private network then use 2nd approach for redirecting, in this case, all contents will load from the private network and user can seen public URL in browser